# Implementing the checkbox for dropdownmenu item flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How to implement the checkboxes for Dropdown menu items in the flutter application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside each `DropdownMenuItem`, you can have `Row` as a child under which you can pass `CheckBox` followed by `Text`. A sample working code to get you started:

```
body: Center(
          child: DropdownButton(
            items: [
              DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Checkbox(
                      onChanged: (bool value) {

                      }, value: _firstValue,
                    ),
                    Text('First'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Checkbox(
                      onChanged: (bool value) {
                      },
                      value: _secValue,
                    ),
                    Text('Second'),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
            onChanged: (value) {
            },
            hint: Text('Select value'),
          )
        )
```

You need to add code per your requirement upon clicking corresponding checkbox inside `setState()` and `onChanged` respectively.

[image]

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: If you click on text instead of checkbox then dropdown closes and that checkbox is chosen

Comment: @temirbek It's because you also have to handle value in `onChanged` callback, something like `switch` for each menu item

Comment: I would try checkboxlisttile so you can select by clicking text too

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error add the value parameter to the `DropMenuItem` Widget and set the `DropdownButton` value to one of the values of your `DropMenuItems`.